# How to send and receive an unexpectable size of json data over http?

Tags: c#, arrays, json, http

I'm implementing a Spring HTTP server, and a C# client to request/response some sets of datas. I found out that sending expectable size of datas are easy, but what shall I do if the data response from the server is unexpectable?

For example, the server will respond with three Strings : [data="",x="",y=""].
But, it can send more than one set of that. Like this.
[data1="", x1="",y1=""], [data2="", x2="",y2=""], [data3="", x3="",y3=""]. 
I don't think this isn't a smart approach to solve these kind of issue. Please, can someone introduce me with another one?

Comment: can you show some code please?

Comment: Your server JSON looks weird. It looks to be an array of Tuple `x`,`y`,`data` but it's not formatted as such. Instead of sending [data='', x='', y=''] + [data1,x1,y1], etc use an array and send it to your client which can then easily parse this as it's a standard, well formed and typed JSON and not an adhoc format. If you absolutely have to do it your way, I'm afraid you'll have to parse it yourself since no standard tool will do it for you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For the C# client, you can use [WebRequest](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.net.webrequest%28v=vs.110%29.aspx) to retrieve your data, and [Json.Net](http://json.codeplex.com/) to deserialize it.

```
private static TResponse GetResponseValue<TResponse>(WebRequest webRequest)
{
    using (var webResponse = webRequest.GetResponse())
    using (var responseStream = webResponse.GetResponseStream())
    using (var streamReader = new StreamReader(responseStream))
    using (var jsonTextReader = new JsonTextReader(streamReader))
    {
        var jsonSerializer = new JsonSerializer();
        return jsonSerializer.Deserialize<TResponse>(jsonTextReader);
    }
}
```